# Using PHP nuSOAP webservice in C#

Tags: c#, php, visual-studio-2012, soap, windows-phone-8

I am working on windows phone project in visual studio 2012 for windows phone.
I am trying use PHP NuSOAP webservice by adding `Service reference`.

Here I followed [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/TechTwaddle/archive/2010/12/30/windows-phone-7-building-a-simple-dictionary-web-client.aspx) sample app. In general the VS will create `Reference.cs` file while adding webservice. You can see reference.cs file contents of dictionary(Sample) app [HERE](http://pastebin.com/aUqeWtp1)

The `Reference.cs` of my webservice of my project [HERE](http://pastebin.com/tCFz9vfp). In my Reference.cs file the interface `SomeMobileServicePortType` is empty.

In Line 19.

```
public interface SomeMobileServicePortType {
}
```

Because of this I not getting any methods of webservice to access in my project. But while adding reference in `Add service Refernce dialogue` it is showing the methods contains in PHP NuSOAP webservice.

I created new instance of webservice class..

```
     ServiceReference1.SomeMobileServicePortTypeClient client = new ServiceReference1.SomeMobileServicePortTypeClient();
```

What is the wrong with PHP webservice. I tried some more webservices [in particular asmx, I didn't get any sample PHP NuSOAP webservice to try]  which are working fine. Can any one tell me How to use PHP NuSOAP service using C#.

==================================================================================

**Edit:**

We are using NuSOAP PHP webservice.

I believe that there is no problem with Webservice. I can't share the WSDL file right now.

[Here](http://www.hirdweb.com/2010/08/15/testing-the-nusoap-webservice/) I got the sample that explains using PHP NuSOAP in C#. I tried with [this](http://www.hirdweb.com/2010/08/15/testing-the-nusoap-webservice/) webservice link. This reference also not giving any methods. The interface is empty like this.

```
 public interface HirdWebExamplePortType {    }
```

So my guess is while using NuSOAP service it is not working in IDE Visual Studio.
[Here](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=cf76631f8b2afa1e&id=CF76631F8B2AFA1E!337&ithint=file,.zip&authkey=!AFzrVZHnz2a8ABs) is my sample windows phone project. Please try this & suggest me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you sure the WSDL of the PHP SOAP service is valid? I guess the problem lies there...

Comment: @chrfin It is fine. While adding reference it is showing the operations that contains in webservice.

Comment: Just because it shows the methods there does not mean it is fine. I already created a few PHP SOAP services and ALWAYS had to "tweak" the WSDL Generation a little bit to get it "really working" for all "clients". May try adding the Service in SOAPui or SoapSonar and see if they work as you expect them?

Comment: I just want add that the webservice working well for author domains well like Android.. Let me check How to use SOAPui and those things. Because I am new to these.

Comment: Still I didn't get solution for this.... Is any one worked before on PHP NuSOAP webservice in C# with IDE Visual Studio... It is essential for me,,Thanks.

Comment: So the service worked fine with SOAPui or SoapSonar?

Comment: @chrfin.. Thank you for reply..
To be frank, I didn't know the what the SOAP services while trying the sample. Here are the example services I tried which are working for me
[ http://geekswithblogs.net/TechTwaddle/archive/2010/12/30/windows-phone-7-building-a-simple-dictionary-web-client.aspx ]
[ http://www.asimishaq.com/resources/easy-soap-web-service-php ] 
[ http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx ]

Comment: Sorry I don't understand? What didn't you know? Which on is NOT working?

Comment: On above comment I gave examples of Services which I tried & all are SOAP services. I don't know whether the service is SOAPui or SoapSonar[the authors didn't mention on their articles]...!
For my case All Soap services are working, & NuSOAP is not working. I tried this [ http://www.hirdweb.com/2010/08/15/testing-the-nusoap-webservice/ ] sample. My webservice also NuSOAP. Please Look at my Edit in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project you supplied is not compatible with this kind of SOAP-Service.

If you add the service to e.g. a Console App it works fine:
[image]

but if you add it to your project (WP Silverlight):
[image]

Check if you can disable SOAP encoding on your service.

Comment: Hi.. chrfin,
As Rathish's answer suggested if I changed to literal it is working fine for me. But I don't think it is proper way. Do you know any other solution to encode the SOAP service...

Comment: `But I don't think it is proper way.` => IMO it IS the proper way to make the service compatible, BUT you should not edit the WSDL manually, but change the generation of the WSDL to be generated that way.

Comment: `It seems that the silverlight version doesn't support RPC/encoded soap and ignores those operations. It does support RPC/Literal soap style`. By changing to `literal` the service working for me. Great thanks for spending your valuable time.

Answer (score 1):

It does support RPC/Literal soap style so we need to change the style from RPC/encoded to RPC/literal. This is actually really easy: Open the wsdl file and modify the input and output operations from

```
<soap:body use="encoded" ..../>

to

<soap:body use="literal" ..../>
```

Reference:
Just go through the below link:

http://guruce.com/blogpost/hosting-webservices-on-wec-using-gsoap-windows-phone-75-mango-client-application#comments